# How can I default a value set inside a Tuple to be "n/a" if it is null?

Tags: c#

I have this C# code:

```
        var result =
            from entry in feed.Descendants(a + "entry")
            let content = entry.Element(a + "content")
            let properties = content.Element(m + "properties")
            let notes = properties.Element(d + "Notes")
            let title = properties.Element(d + "Title")
            let partitionKey = properties.Element(d + "PartitionKey")
            where partitionKey.Value.Substring(2, 2) == "06" && title != null && notes != null
            select new Tuple<string, string>(title.Value, notes.Value);
```

It works only if I select notes != null

Rather than do this how can I set the value of notes.Value in the Tuple to be "n/a" if notes.Value is a null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [null coallescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `??`

```
select new Tuple<string, string>(title.Value, notes.Value ?? "n/a");
```

Note you can also use `Tuple.Create` instead of the tuple constructor:

```
select Tuple.Create(title.Value, notes.Value ?? "n/a");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
notes.Value ?? "n/a"
```

Which says "get the value if not null, otherwise use the secondary argument."

Answer (score 1):

In case of `Enumerable String`, you can use null coalescing operator at the `let` expression level to have default in case of null

```
let notes = properties.Element(d + "Notes") ?? "n/a"
 let title = properties.Element(d + "Title") ?? "n/a"
```

then rewrite the where clause as

```
  where partitionKey.Value.Substring(2, 2) == "06"
  select new Tuple<string, string>(title.Value, notes.Value);
```

As pointed, in case of XElement, you can alternately have

```
    where partitionKey.Value.Substring(2, 2) == "06"
    select new Tuple<string, string>(title.Value??"n/a", notes.Value??"n/a");
```

Comment: ?? Can be applied to XElement and string :-(

Comment: @Gemma, I haven't tested XElement but with Enumerable String. If you think it's going break then go with you logic excluding the where and select clause. I modified the code.